# Is every polynomial with integer coefficients prime in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ also prime in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, factoring, prime-factorization, maximal-and-prime-ideals

The question is as in the title:

Is every polynomial with integer coefficients prime in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ also  prime in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Comment: Yes, by Gauss's Lemma

Answer (score 4):

This is not true for polynomials of degree $0$. The polynomial $7$ is a prime element in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ yet not in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ (as there it is a unit). 
This works of course  for any prime element of $\mathbb{Z}$, that is plus/minus the prime numbers.

For polynomials of positive degree it is true by [Gauss's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_lemma_%28polynomial%29) as remarked in a comment. (Also note that the converse, that may seem obvious, is not strictly true for reasons similar to the one mentioned at the start.)